# Create file list in ascending order based on filename

Tags: ls, sort

I need to create a file list which display the file name in ascending order. My file name has file pattern: FILE.YYYYMMDD.XXX

For example:

```
$ ls -ltr
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 honle 1036 Apr 14  2020 FILE.20200102.001
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 honle 426832 Apr 14  2020 FILE.20200102.002
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 honle 426832 Apr 14  2020 FILE.20200102.003
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 honle 426832 Apr 10  2020 FILE.20200110.001
-rw-r--r--. 1 honle 426832 Apr 14 22:50 FILE.20200220.001
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 honle 1036 Apr 15 16:30 FILE.20200110.001
```

Noted for input why FILE.20200120.002 before FILE.20200220.001. FILE.20200120.002  was processed and coming to current dir before FILE.20200220.001. That is why i need to sort it based on the YYYYMMDD.XXX filename pattern.

Desired output:

```
FILE.20200102.001
FILE.20200102.002
FILE.20200102.003
FILE.20200110.001
FILE.20200120.002
FILE.20200220.001
```

The time file was created is not in order so I can't use ls -ltr. Any idea how I can sort them? I am using Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Post the desired output.

Comment: Shouldn't `FILE.20200120.002` be before `FILE.20200220.001`?

Comment: Why is `FILE.20200120.002` after `FILE.20200220.001`?

Comment: Hi, the file FILE.20200120.002 was done process and sent to dest dir before FILE.20200120.001. That was why it was before FILE.20200220.001 when i do ls

Comment: @RLe Only if you used `ls -t` to ask `ls` to sort by "last modified" timestamp.  It is unclear what order you want the files in. Sorted on filename, or sorted by modification time.

Comment: @Kusalananda sort by filename pattern time

Comment: @RLe In that case, your expected output is wrong.  Also, what is `.HH.` that you have mentioned a couple of times but that doesn't seem to be part of the actual filenames?

Comment: Hi I edit the input

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is to get the filenames in a single column rather than in the multi-column format that `ls` produces, then you may use the `-1`  ("minus one") option to `ls`:

```
ls -1
```

The filenames would be sorted by name.

---

```
printf '%s\n' FILE.*
```

Assuming that the pattern `FILE.*` matches all relevant filenames, and nothing else, the above command would also print the filenames in lexicographical order, each on a line by itself, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `printf` instead of a simple `ls -l` here?

Comment: @terdon `ls -1`, that would give a single column output. After re-reading, I'm a bit confused as to what the issue is. Possibly they are just over-specifying options... `-t` would sort on `mtime`, but just leave that option off then...

Comment: Yes, I think the OP most likely isn't aware of `-1`, but that's why I'm waiting to see if they answer my comment about the ordering. Assuming the desired output is wrong, they just need `ls -1`, methinks.